# Two passes through an array O(n) or O(2n)

Tags: big-o

I was on interview cake practicing some questions, and on question [2](https://www.interviewcake.com/question/java/product-of-other-numbers) the solution given uses two separate for loops (not nested) and the solution provider claims that he/she solved it in O(n) time. From my understanding that would be O(2n) time. Am I wrong in thinking this, or did the solution provider make a mistake?

Excerpt from interview cake :
[image]

Comment: O(n) == O(2n) == O(kn).  Constants don't matter, only the scaling factor.

Comment: O(2n) is amortized to O(n) since the factor "2" has a disproportionately small influence compared to "n" (in a worst-case scenario)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big-O notation gives you a hint on how do your algorithm execution time depends on the input data. When you see that time complexity is *O(n)* you understand that there is a **linear** dependency between input and execution time. The constants are not mentioned.

By definition *Ο(g(n))* is a **set of functions** for each of which the following statement holds: There exists such positive constants *c* and *n<sub>0</sub>* that *0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n)* holds for all *n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>*. You see the definition is using an arbitrary constant *c*, if your *g(n)* itself has a constant that would not make any difference.

Eventually we have: *O(cg(n))* = *O(g(n))*. In your particular case *O(cn)* = *O(2n)* = *O(n)*. They both represent the same set of functions.

Comment: So then if on an interview the interviewer asks for an algorithm to be developed that runs in O(n) time, and I write one in O(2n) time, that shouldn't be a major issue?

Comment: @Hossam, it is just **redundant** to say *O(2n)*, because it is the same as *O(n)*. I don't think that would influence your interview results somehow :).

Answer (score 4):

Big-O notation is most useful to see how code scales. That is, if I double the size of the array, how much longer will the code take to run? If your code is `O(n)`, it will take twice as long, whereas if it is `O(n^2)`, it will take 4 times as long, and so on. In this case, regardless of the fact that you make a pass through the loop twice, doubling the size of your array will take twice as long as before (twice as long for each of the loops).